# how to create a fast scroll over an alphabetic textviews and print the first character?

Tags: android, scroll

I have multiple textviews in main.xml

```
<LinearLayout...
>
<textview adndroid:tag="A">
...
till to Z.
</LinearLayout>
```

I need an fastscroll over all the textViews . How to do that? Need some help.

I have to print the character when pressing A or B..and so on. How to do that?

```
a1.setOnTouchListener(newOnTouchListener(){
public boolean onTouch(View w,MotionEvent event)
{
//? WHAT TO WRITE HERE?
 I NEED TO PRINT ON THE SCREEN A because  I CLICK ON A TEXTVIEW.
 I LIKE TO PRINT THE CHARACTER A IN A BOX (like the one from contact list android)

}

});
```

Here is an example code: [link](http://www.google.ro/imgres?um=1&hl=ro&sa=N&biw=1024&bih=641&tbm=isch&tbnid=bNyiUOO2XN1w5M%3a&imgrefurl=https://motorola-enterprise.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/48594/~/droid-x---contacts&docid=Gvzcu0ZvnDcdHM&imgurl=https://motorola-global-eng.custhelp.com/rnt/rnw/img/enduser/droidxdialercontactssearch2.jpg&w=480&h=432&ei=z7B5T_jXEsTysgbXsKjMBA&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=89&vpy=193&dur=908&hovh=213&hovw=237&tx=145&ty=99&sig=108508964887658012348&page=1&tbnh=116&tbnw=129&start=0&ndsp=20&ved=1t:429,r:14,s:0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView02" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout
    ....
>
 <textview  ...yourtextview   >
 ...
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

For the second part of your question, I think you have to add `android:clickable="true"` to all your textViews and handle that with code.

Otherwise, you could use a ListView with the `setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()`, in this way it's easier ...

Comment: Thx for reponse. I need to print the A,B ..or C... character when clicking on the specific textview. How to do that?

Comment: i've edited my question. a1 is the textview coresponfing to character A

Comment: what does that mean you need to print them?  You mean like a Toast?  OR do you need to write them to some object?

Comment: well I need to have the view as in the contact list. like here: http://www.google.ro/imgres?um=1&hl=ro&sa=N&biw=1024&bih=641&tbm=isch&tbnid=bNyiUOO2XN1w5M:&imgrefurl=https://motorola-enterprise.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/48594/~/droid-x---contacts&docid=Gvzcu0ZvnDcdHM&imgurl=https://motorola-global-eng.custhelp.com/rnt/rnw/img/enduser/droidxdialercontactssearch2.jpg&w=480&h=432&ei=z7B5T_jXEsTysgbXsKjMBA&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=89&vpy=193&dur=908&hovh=213&hovw=237&tx=145&ty=99&sig=108508964887658012348&page=1&tbnh=116&tbnw=129&start=0&ndsp=20&ved=1t:429,r:14,s:0

Comment: when clicking the A to have like..in the link belog, when clicking the b..to print th b and so on. If I move my finder up and down list a..b..c..and so on

Comment: Thank you very much.Inside the method clicklistener how to but the A,B..in a little box? I need somethinf like a fastscroll over a listview

Comment: How about creating a custom dialog box? Try to see here: [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Comment: should I add it in on clicklistener?

Comment: If I understand correctly, when your user clicks on a TextView, he should see a small textbox containing a letter.
You have to handle the user clicks with the listener and create there the dialogbox passing the letter. Try to see documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ShowingADialog).

Answer (score 0):

At first specify layout for chars in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list_products"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/chars_layout"
        android:layout_width="26dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        >

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in code add chars to your layout:

```
     private void addCharsForScrolling(LinearLayout charsLayout, ArrayList<String> sectionList) {
            Collections.sort(sectionList);
            sections = new String[sectionList.size()];

            for (int m = 0; m < sectionList.size(); m++) {
                sections[m] = sectionList.get(m);
                        addScrollText(charsLayout, sectionList.get(m),false);

            }
        }
```

Here is code for sectionlist:

```
    private void findChars (ArrayList<BrandsRestaurantsModel> brands,  ArrayList <ProductLists.ResourantsWithPlace> imgstructure){
        LinearLayout charsLayout = (LinearLayout) this.rootview.findViewById(R.id.chars_layout);

            mapIndex = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
            sectionList = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int x = 0; x < brands.size(); x++) {
                sectionList.add(brands.get(x).getCh());
                if (!mapIndex.containsKey(brands.get(x).getCh()))
                    mapIndex.put(brands.get(x).getCh(), x);
            }
            Set<String> sectionLetters = mapIndex.keySet();
            ArrayList<String> sectionList = new ArrayList<String>(sectionLetters);
            addCharsForScrolling(charsLayout, sectionList);

    }
```